# Will a source file be recompiled multiple times if its nested header file is modified?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header-files

[image]

In the attached image, if D.h is modified, will Visual Studio recompile A.cpp twice? Or will it be recompiled only once?

Comment: Thanks! I should have added that I'm working on a really big legacy project that uses Visual Studio as a build system. I have never used GNU make, so I'm not sure how/if the linked question answers my question.

Comment: @Marsupito since A.h doesn't need compilation on it's own, but only from include statements in A.cpp, I don't see why any sufficently smart build system would decide to compile A.cpp twice or more.

Comment: @Marsupito specifically for the msvc build system (Visual studio toolchain) you should be aware, that these tend to use a mechanism called precompiled header files (.pch), which is usually used to optimize some compiler runs. This may in fact affect how many of your source files need to be recompiled, because of header changes. Not multiple times, but more .cpp files you might expect.

Comment: Why not try it yourself and then look at the build output of Visual Studio to see what happens?  I feel like learning by doing is better than just learning by asking for theories from strangers.

Comment: You’re right. I should have done that. It’s still great though because I have learned more than I expected from everyone here. Thanks a lot for all of your thoughts!

Comment: Unless you explicitly do something to force multiple recompilation (e.g. set up a rule that regenerates one or more other source files or headers if `D.h` changes), most build systems will only recompile `A.cpp` once.    Most developers don't need to set up such things, so there will be no problem of multiple compilation.   If your project *does* have such a rule, then there will be a very specific reason for it that should be documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Compiling `a.cpp` once is sufficient to produce an object file that incorporates all the latest changes from the header files (if they are relevant to the code in `a.cpp`).

Your build system should be considered to be buggy and broken if it has to compile `a.cpp` twice during a single build, because the second compilation would be just redoing the same work as the first compilation and producing the same result.

Comment: So because D.h is modified, the build system will figure out that A.cpp needs to be recompiled, and then from A.cpp, it’ll parse all the changes in the header files that A.cpp includes.

Comment: I've also just learned that including A.h and X.h in A.cpp basically means the entire contents of A.h and X.h (and their included headers too, which are B.h, C.h, and D.h) are copied to A.cpp before it is compiled. That explains how the compiler figures out A.cpp needs to be re-compiled. It all makes sense to me now. Thanks again for your clarification!